# script not running second function after taking user input

Tags: batch-file

My goal is to first prompt, echo the line, issue the next prompt, then display `press any key to exit...`.

I'm not sure why my [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) isn't issuing the second prompt.

```
@echo off

::deploying to test
set /p tdeploy="Deploy to test: [y/n]"

IF /I "%tdeploy%"=="y"(
    call :deploy_test
    if /I "%ERRORLEVEL%" NEQ "0"(
        echo Deploy test failed
    )
)

::deploying to argos
set /p adeploy="Deploy to argos: [y/n]"

IF /I "%adeploy%"=="y"(
    call :deploy_argos
    if /I "%ERRORLEVEL%" NEQ "0"(
        echo Deploy argos failed
    )
)
set /p DUMMY=Press any key to exit...


:deploy_test
ECHO deploying test!
goto :eof


:deploy_argos
ECHO deploying argos!
goto :eof

:eof
set /p DUMMY=Press any key to exit.222..
```

Comment: looks like if you enter Y on the first prompt, it sends it to `:eof` at the end - bypassing the second prompt altogether.

Comment: Within a block statement `(a parenthesised series of statements)`, the **entire** block is parsed and **then** executed. Any `%var%` within the block will be replaced by that variable's value **at the time the block is parsed** - before the block is executed - the same thing applies to a `FOR ... DO (block)`.Hence, `IF (something) else (somethingelse)` will be executed using the values of `%variables%` at the time the `IF` is encountered.Using `delayedexpansion`, the run-time value of a variable is accessed by `!var!`. `%var%` is always the parse-time vauel

Comment: You could also use conventional `errorlevel` processing `if ERRORLEVEL1  (`. `IF ERRORLEVEL n` is TRUE if the runtime (ie. current) `errorlevel` is n **or greater than n**. `IF ERRORLEVEL 0` is therefore always true. `IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1` is a test for errorlevel=0. So is `IF %ERRORLEVEL%==0`, except that the former can be used within a block but the latter cannot.

Comment: Insert a _space_ in front of the opening parenthesis in `IF /I "%tdeploy%"=="y" (` and so forth! After `set /p DUMMY=...` you need to place `goto :eof` to not fall into the `:deploy_test` section unintentionally. And as others already mentioned you need [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for `!ErrorLevel!`. Instead of `set /P` for yes/no entries you could use the [`choice` command](https://ss64.com/nt/choice.html)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually prefer to structure it as a nested `IF ELSE` to avoid a bunch of `GOTO` commands and having to figure out error levels:

```
@echo off

REM deploying to test
set /p tdeploy="Deploy to test: [y/n]"

if /i "%tdeploy%" == "y" (
    echo           deploying test!
    ) else (
    if /i "%tdeploy%" == "n" (
        echo           deploy test cancelled
        ) else (
        echo           seriously, there were only two options...
        )
    )
)

REM deploying to argos
set /p adeploy="Deploy to test: [y/n]"

if /i "%adeploy%" == "y" (
    echo           deploying test!
    ) else (
    if /i "%adeploy%" == "n" (
        echo           deploy test cancelled
        ) else (
        echo           seriously, there were only two options...
        )
    )
)

pause
```

The `pause` will be your "Press any key to continue..." - the rest of the spacing is just to make it more visible.

Comment: That worked great, but I had to add: `set /p adeploy="Deploy to argos: [y/n]"` 
 right after tdeploy

Comment: Why did you remove the quotes around the comparison expressions? Keep them in order to avoid trouble when a user does not enter anything. Also always add the `/I` switch (you missed some)...

Comment: no specific reason - I was just letting the final `else` statement handle anything that wasn't a `y` or an `n`; generally I would quote out everything, but here I was just trying to display the format. good catch on the missing `/i` switches though - my copy/paste game was not strong here. i'll go ahead and update it with both of your comments so it'll be more useful to anyone else who may end up using it!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `choice.exe` for your `Y`,`N` questions:

```bat
@Echo Off

Rem Deploying to test
Choice /M "Deploy to test"
If "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (Call :deploy_test
    If ErrorLevel 1 Echo Deploy test failed)

Rem Deploying to argos
Choice /M "Deploy to argos"
If "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="1" (Call :deploy_argos
    If ErrorLevel 1 Echo Deploy test failed)

Echo Press any key to exit...
Timeout /T -1 >NUL
GoTo :EOF

:deploy_test
Echo Deploying test!
Timeout /T 3 /NoBreak >NUL
Exit /B 0

:deploy_argos
Echo Deploying argos!
Timeout /T 3 /NoBreak >NUL
Exit /B 1
```

In the example above, I have used two different exit codes, to simulate the returned error level for each of the two deployment options.